# Error: incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to char (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < (size-1); i++) {
    for (int j = i - 1, k = i + 1; j >= 0 && k < size; j--, k++) {
        if (thelist[j] == thelist[k]) {
            if (k - j + 1 >= 6) {
                for(int p = 0; p < 20; p++){
                    potentialPalindromes[p] = Arrays.copyOfRange(thelist, j, k + 1);
                }
            }
        } else break;
    }
}
```

, given that that

- potentialPalindromes is a char array, and
- thelist is a char array,

I want to copy a range of characters from the `thelist` array and deposit it into another array. But the compiler rejects my code, saying I can't convert char[] to char.  What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Both arrays that iam using are char arrays

Comment: ... and this is a very basic error. The type on the left hand side of an assignment statement must be the same as the one on the right, or a parent of the one on the right, or automatically converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

potentialPalindromes[p] is a char. You can't put a char array into a char. You should probably have potentialPalindromes be an array of char arrays, i.e. char[][].

Also, why not just use a String instead of char array.